# Is there an ArcGIS Pro tool that snaps a point feature class to another point feature class based on a matching attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, coordinates, snapping

I have two point feature classes with similar attributes. One point layer has update coordinates while the other has raw coordinate locations. I would like to snap points with raw coordinates to the points with updated coordinates if their site ids match.

[image: Two point feature classes]

I would like to snap green points(raw) to red points(updated) only if there site ids match rather than their closest point.

Is there a tool that does this?

Comment: I don't know of a tool that does this, could be wrong of course. A simple workflow could be do a JOIN based on ID numbers. Then use the XY Table To Point and select your updated x/y column.

Comment: Esri makes toolboxes of primatives. There's rarely one tool that meets all requirements, but often several tools that accomplish the hard parts, and you just have to tie them together. They even provide multiple means of tying them. I'd start with a Near Table, then walk the many-to-many join/relate to identify the closest pairs. Unfortunately, there's so many potential solutions, that this doesn't fit the Focused question/Best answer model used here.

Comment: There is a tool, it's called Snap https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm but I think adding XY coordinates to the new locations https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm and then an attribute join based on site ID followed by points from XY table by https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm should get you there. Python would be easier: digest the correct locations in a dict {SiteID:[X,Y]} then in an update cursor with SHAPE@XY lookup the dict to change XY.